# PyGame development bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am developing a Space Invaders clone using Python 3.5.1 and have stumbled upon an error which I am not sure how to fix. I'm trying to keep a sprite inside the window and my code only works to keep the sprite from leaving the top and left sides of it. Here is my code. Thanks.

```
import pygame
import sys

width = 500
height = 700

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

score = 0

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        pos_x, pos_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        player_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = pos_x
        self.rect.y = pos_y

        player_rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("enemy.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("laser.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

player = Ship()
allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
allSprites.add(player)

running = True
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(black)
    player.update()
    allSprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The object already has a `Rect` object in `self.rect`; you aren't actually calling the `clamp_ip` method on the right `Rect`.

It may be enough to call `self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)` instead of even bothering with getting the image `Rect` at all. The builtin `draw` method of the Sprite `Group`*should* just draw the image in the sprite's `Rect` if I recall correctly, so just make sure you're only updating the sprite's `Rect` correctly.

```
def update(self):
    self.rect.topleft = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if not screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
```

Comment: There's no need to check `not screen_rect.contains(self.rect)` explicitly. Just calling `self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)` is enough.

Comment: This is true - I guess I'm used to generic colliders that get replaced with specific ones later on, so `if passes_the_test: do_the_thing()` seemed good. But, you're right of course.

Answer (score 0):

Change you `def update(self):` with the following:

```
    def update(self):
        pos_tup = pygame.mouse.get_pos() # edit fix
        pos_x = pos_tup[0] # edit fix
        pos_y = pos_tup[1] # edit fix
        player_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        if pos_x < 0:
            self.rect.x = 0
        elif pos_x > width:
            self.rect.x = width
        else:
            self.rect.x = pos_x
        if pos_y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
        elif pos_y > height:
            self.rect.y = height
        else:
            self.rect.y = pos_y
        player_rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
```

Comment: Damn it.  I forgot that get_pos() returns a tuple.

Comment: You'll think I'm joking but I still get the same error

Comment: you're already updating `self.rect` directly, why do you need to get the `player_rect` via `image.get_rect()`? Moreover, calling `get_rect()` on a `Surface` object returns a *new* `Rect` object, not the actual `Rect` of the image.